# Flex component communication

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, components

I use a popup loaded from different MXML file:

```
private function showAddPopUp():void{
    addPopUP = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, add_popup, true);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(addPopUP);
}
```

That file is as follows (add_popus.mxml):

```
<mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%" paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5">
    <mx:Label text="Enter name of the source:" />
    <mx:TextInput width="100%" id="textName" />
    <mx:Label text="Enter URL for the source:" />
    <mx:TextInput width="100%" id="textURL" />
    <mx:HBox width="100%">
        <mx:Button label="OK" id="buttonOK" textAlign="center"/>
        <mx:Button label="Cancel" id="buttonCancel" click="PopUpManager.removePopUp(this)" textAlign="center"/>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:VBox>
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass text values from text inputs to the main component after buttonOK is clicked in the popup. I tried custom events, but it didn't work. Documentation is not very helpful. I will appreciate any ideas.

Full code is here: http://github.com/jbajor/Newspapair

Comment: Why didn't custom events work? Did you get errors? Wasn't it possible to get a listener for that event?

Comment: yeah, custom events are the proper way of doing this. If they don't work, then let us help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by passing strings from text fields? something like `this.owner.someMethod(textName.text);`? That is not the best way of doing it - event propagation is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch an event from the button click

```
<!-- AddPopUp.mxml -->
<mx:Button label="OK" id="buttonOK" textAlign="center" 
    click="dispatchEvent(new Event(POPUP_DONE))"/>
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    public static const POPUP_DONE:String = "popupDone";
]]>
</mx:Script>
```

And listen to it in the other class. `event.target` will give you a handle to the popup.

```
private function showAddPopUp():void
{
    var addPopUp:AddPopup = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, add_popup, true);
    addPopUp.addEventListener(AddPopUp.POPUP_DONE, onPopupDone);
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(addPopUP);
}
private function onPopupDone(e:Event):void
{
    var popup:AddPopUp = AddPopUp(e.target);
    trace(popup.textName.text);
}
```

Comment: It does work, but I am still trying to pass strings from text fields.